Creating a Scratch Org returns timeout error
I'm trying to create a Scratch org based on a Shape.  The definition and errors are below.  What can I set to resolve the timeout?
{

  "orgName": "ClientName",
  "sourceOrg": "00D8d00000xxxx",
  "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi","DevOpsCenter"],
  "settings": {
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "devHubSettings": {
            "enableDevOpsCenterGA": true
            }  
  }
}


18:10:51.336 sf org:create:scratch --definition-file
config/project-scratch-def.json --alias Scratch2 --duration-days 30
--set-default --json  ended with exit code 69

The scratch org did not complete within your wait time

18:25:19.924 sf org:create:scratch --definition-file
config/project-scratch-def.json --alias Scratch2 --duration-days 30
--set-default --json 18:30:24.308 sf org:create:scratch --definition-file config/project-scratch-def.json --alias Scratch2 --duration-days 30 --set-default --json  ended with exit code 68

The client has timed out.

While unusual, creating a Scratch Org can take longer than the default timeout. Use the -w parameter to increase the timeout.
sf org create scratch -w 100 -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a Scratch2 --duration-days 30 -s

Here, we wait up to 100 minutes to create the Scratch Org.

I have encountered an issue where scratch org creation was timing out due to the presence of "ancestorVersion": "HIGHEST" in the sfdx-project.json file.
They got stuck in New status indefinitely.
I have successfully created scratch orgs with this setting present in a different context, and I don't understand why it caused issues in my current case. But removing it allowed the orgs to be created again while I figure that out...
